# Component design problem statement in angular 2.0 and above

Tags: angular, typescript, components

Problem statement - 
Two input control display in the same page and both input controls belongs in separate component.
When we put the value in first input text box, its calculate the square value and display in to second input controls, vice versa if change value in the second text box its calculate square value and update to first text control.
How i can design the component structure to achieve the requirement in the Angular 8?

Answer (score 0):

Simplly use ngmodal and calculate values in TS file 
ngModal will help you with transporting values from HTML to ts and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Here we are first understand the implementation problem then go to the solutions part-

**Problem**

> First if you change value from first control text box its will execute the ngOnChange() life cycle hook and calculate square value and update to second text box, but once you update value in to second text box its will again call ngOnChange() again changes call and update the value in to first text box ,this event continues call infinite time.

**Solution**

**Create structure of Component design**

> child.component.html

```
<input type="text" name="name1" id="txtName2" [(ngModel)]="childText" (change)="valuechange2($event.target.value)" />
```

> child.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange, SimpleChanges, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'child-component',
        templateUrl: './child.component.html'
    })
    export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
        @Input() childText: number;
        @Output() text2Change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
        constructor() { }
        ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
            let currentVal = changes.childText.currentValue;
            let previousVal = changes.childText.previousValue;
            if (currentVal != previousVal) {
                this.childText = currentVal * currentVal;
            }
        }
        valuechange2(val: number) {
            this.text2Change.emit(val);
        }
    }
```

> Child2.component.html

```
<input type="text" name="name1" id="txtName3" [(ngModel)]="childText" (change)="valuechange2($event.target.value)" />
```

> Child2.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange, SimpleChanges, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child1-component',
    templateUrl: './child1.component.html'
})
export class Child1Component implements OnChanges {
    @Input() childText: number;
    @Output() text2Change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

    constructor() { }
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        let currentVal = changes.childText.currentValue;
        let previousVal = changes.childText.previousValue;
        if (currentVal != previousVal) {
            this.childText = currentVal * currentVal;
        }
    }
    valuechange2(val: number) {
        this.text2Change.emit(val);
    }
}
```

**Parent Component**

> app.component.html

```
<child-component [childText]="text1" (text2Change)="childChange($event)"></child-component>
<child1-component [childText]="text2" (text2Change)="child1Change($event)"></child1-component>
```

> app.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { of, merge } from 'rxjs';
    import { mergeMap, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit, OnChanges {
      title = 'my-app';

      text1: number;
      text2: number;

      ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log(changes);
      }

      childChange(child: number) {
        this.text2 = child;
      }
      child1Change(child: number) {
        this.text1 = child;
      }
    }
```